# Inserting text from a var into a WebSQL table

Tags: database, html, insert, web-sql

I'm having a lot of trouble inserting text stored in a var into a table. Check out my code:

```
function updateTable(){
    var text = "finally";

        db.transaction(
            function(transaction) {

                    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Comentario (ComentarioCirc1, ComentarioCirc2) VALUES (text, "2")');
            }
        );
    }
```

I've tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked. It should be so simple to do, what am I doing wrong? No data is inserted in the table and no error messages are shown also,

Answer (score 0):

to fix your query you need to add value of text variable, like this:

```
transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Comentario (ComentarioCirc1, ComentarioCirc2) VALUES ("' + text + '", "2")');
```

but what you really should do is use parameterized SQL, like this:

```
transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Comentario (ComentarioCirc1, ComentarioCirc2) VALUES (?, "2")', [text]);
```

and if you want to know whether query succeeded or not you should pass success and error calbacks as third and fourth argument of executeSql.

I'd also suggest befriending [webdatabase specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase) as it will answer a lot of other questions you will likely have ;)